# Firebase and iOS: FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain "MISSING_IDENTIFIER" when trying to login with custom token

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've recently migrated to the new version of Firebase. I'm using the new SDK in my iOS app.

I'm using Firebase 3.2.0 and have hit the following error when sign in with custom token:

```
Optional(Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd290f3dc50 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey=<CFBasicHash 0x7fd2931787a0 [0x10e5db7b0]>{type = immutable dict, count = 3,

entries =>

0 : <CFString 0x7fd2931669b0 [0x10e5db7b0]>{contents = "message"} = <CFString 0x7fd29318e280 [0x10e5db7b0]>{contents = "MISSING_IDENTIFIER"}

1 : errors = <CFArray 0x7fd2931554b0 [0x10e5db7b0]>{type = immutable, count = 1, values = (

0 : <CFBasicHash 0x7fd293141000 [0x10e5db7b0]>{type = immutable dict, count = 3,

entries =>

0 : reason = invalid

1 : message = <CFString 0x7fd2931a0070 [0x10e5db7b0]>{contents = "MISSING_IDENTIFIER"}

2 : domain = global

}



)}

2 : code = <CFNumber 0xb000000000001903 [0x10e5db7b0]>{value = +400, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}

}

}}, error_name=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.})
```

I don't know what "MISSING_IDENTIFIER" means.

Does anyone have the same issue?

Comment: Hi, I'm new to Firebase. I'm trying out custom authentication. If I want a user to sign in with a username and password, how would I do it. Do I ave to create a custom token , if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem.
When server generates custom token, the value of "uid" is required.
"IDENTIFIER" means the value "uid".

[**Generate Custom Token**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server#use_the_firebase_server_sdk)

```
$payload = array(
      "iss" => $service_account_email,
      "sub" => $service_account_email,
      "aud" => "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
      "iat" => $now_seconds,
      "exp" => $now_seconds+(60*60),  // Maximum expiration time is one hour
      "uid" => $uid,
      "claims" => array(
          "premium_account" => $is_premium_account
      );
```